# How to make selenium to give control to me(user)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was using selenium(python) to first login to a page and then download something. But the page asks to enter some custom characters to login. So can I make selenium give control to me temporarily, so that I can enter the characters and then selenium can continue the process forward. Is there a way to do this? Or maybe another way to bypass it?

Comment: can you focus on what you need to type and have selenium type the characters for you?

Comment: What kind of custom characters? I think it's easier to pass them than doing something as you mention. And also I think this is not possible (at-least with Selenium, I am not familiar with other frameworks).

Comment: Another way can be to put wait and then you can type.

But again, if you have to do it manually at the initial stage then what is the point of automating it

Comment: The characters change every time

Comment: Are you referring to Captcha

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't remember the word